# What does $x \in \{y | p(y)\} \Longleftrightarrow p(x)$ mean? Is it even true?

Tags: logic

Is there a name for : $x \in \{y | p(y)\} \Longleftrightarrow p(x)$? Is this even true, and if so, what does it mean? An example might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "set-builder notation" $\{y\mid p(y)\}$ says that the elements of the aforementioned set are **precisely** the ones that fulfill the formula $p(y)$.  Thus, to say that $x\in \{y \mid p(y)\}$ means that $p(x)$.  This is a definition of the notation.

For example, take the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^2=1\}$.  The solutions to $x^2=1$ are $-1,1$, and thus the only elements of the set are $-1$ and $1$; no other element of $\mathbb{R}$ can be an element of the set because they wouldn't fulfill the condition set on $x$.

A typical way to read the set-builder notation is as "The set of all $y$ such that $p(y)$ is true".

Comment: Thanks. Can we use this to prove $a^{\smile \smile} = a$ where $a$ is a set? How does textual substitution work with this equivalence?

Comment: If by that notation you mean the complement of the complement of $a$, relative to some set, then you could do that.  It's just a double negation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $x$ is among the set of values $y$ for which the predicate $p(y)$ holds, then (by definition of that set) the predicate $p(x)$ must hold. For an example, take any predicate ($p(y)$: $y$ is a composite number will do fine) and take any $x$ in the domain of the predicate (in the example, any number). Just read what it says.